# How can I select specific groups after using xray.DataArray.groupby?

Tags: python, python-xarray

For example, I want to select **DJF** precipitation values using:

```
ds_weighted = ds.groupby('time.season').mean('time')

DJF = ds['precip'].sel(season='DJF').values
```

I don't want to average over the whole time period (don't need the `.mean('time')` part), just to get the `DJF` values out of that period.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need most groups, you shouldn't use `groupby`. Instead, select out the values you're interested in, e.g., `ds.precip.sel(time=(ds['time.season'] == 'DFJ')).mean('time')`